# Is it possible to publish the same app with different package names?

Tags: android, gradle, android-flavors

I have a project where I have to build many apps that are basically the same, but changing the name of the company...

So I would like to change the package name and colors with flavors and publish those app in the store (with different package names)

Is it possible?

Comment: If you are asking "will an app store accept this", [that is off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic). If you are just asking "can I change the application ID and colors using product flavors?", then the answer is yes.

Comment: I am not asking about app store... But thanks for remember me, I take a look at this. 

So... If I change the application id, but don't change the package name in the manifest and install both apps it will work ok? Normally every Java app has to be an unique package name... right?

Comment: "If I change the application id, but don't change the package name in the manifest and install both apps it will work ok?" -- correct. "Normally every Java app has to be an unique package name... right?" -- Java does not care. *Android* requires unique application IDs, and the default application ID is the package name from the `package` attribute on the `<manifest>` element in the manifest. But, in Gradle, you can override the `applicationId` to be something else, leaving `package` alone (so you do not need to change `R` references and such).

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare! It was really helpful!

Comment: I don't understand why this question got down voted... I am pretty sure I am following the guide lines. It's not about a App Store policy, it's about code. Well, I got my answer, so thank you =].

Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. 
You need to use a **different Package name, different
App Name, different Application id** & Colour - you can use anything you want

Then it will be two separate App. 
So Can publish that two Apps in the Same Playstore Account or Different Account.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to publish app. but different app name,package name and app id in same developer console account in android.